# What are all of the possible punctuation that are used within words in the majority of languages?

Tags: written-language, punctuation

I know it's potentially a bit of an odd question, but I am working on an app that needs to analyze text that can be written in any of the most common languages. What I need to know is what punctuation/special characters are used within words among the most common languages? For example apostrophes are used in English (eg. I'm) within words, particularly for contractions. Are there any other characters I should know about? Hyphens perhaps?

Thanks

Comment: Downvoters, explain yourselves.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer it's more a programming question than a linguistics question.

Comment: @melboiko There are far more technical questions asked in this SE, but anyway there are linguistics angles, for example a single symbol is punctuation in one language but a diacritic or even a letter or a word in another.

Comment: Need the system handle user-generated data?  Users may use symbols like `'` for `´` or `@` for `ը`.  For your application is `&` punctuation or a word?  Do you care about `—` which has a grammatical function in Russian where it can replace the copula?

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer sure, writing systems is a subfield of linguistics. But what they want to do is the kind of thing that programmers do, more than linguists. Splitting a text string into words, in a language-independent way, is trickier than it sounds, and depends on multi-step algorithms working with a database of individual character properties; it's more complex than "which punctuation goes within words". Luckily, such algorithms and databases are already provided by Unicode and implemented in various free libraries, as pointed in my answer. Stackoverflow could give even more pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is [Unicode text segmentation](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/).  Look into the "Word Boundaries" section.  If you can't understand it, read a Unicode manual first—Unicode's own book is free and easy to understand.  You can use a ready-made Unicode library like [libicu](http://userguide.icu-project.org/boundaryanalysis), rather than coding the Unicode algorithms yourself.

Do not be lazy and try to avoid this with a hacky regex or something.  The *only* way to properly support languages in text processing (for example, to locate "words" in text in a language-independent way) is by understanding Unicode and its algorithms.  If you ignore this, you *will* mishandle something for a user somewhere.

Comment: This question and answer needs to be on stackoverflow proper.